# How to import my own icons to my function iconNameFromType?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react

I have component with map, it renders to every type different icon and count:

```
                    <div className="Items">
                        {doctypes && <React.Fragment>
                            {doctypes.map(({ type, count }) => {
                                return(
                                    <div onClick={() => {
                                        this.props.rootStore.navToSecondScreen(type);
                                        }}>
                                        <Statistic inverted>
                                            <Statistic.Value >
                                                <Icon className={iconNameFromType(type)}/>

                                                <p className="count">{count}</p>
                                            </Statistic.Value>
                                            <Statistic.Label>
                                                <p className="type">{type}</p>
                                            </Statistic.Label>
                                        </Statistic>
                                    </div>  
                                );
                            })}
                        </React.Fragment>}
                    </div>
```

and I want to replace semantic icons with my own icons, but how can I put them in const mapping = {}, like I tried below? Or there are some other versions, how to do that?

```
import { SemanticICONS } from "semantic-ui-react";

const html = require ("~/src/assets/html.png");
const pdf = require ("~/src/assets/pdf.png");


//WHAT I HAVE
export function iconNameFromType(type): SemanticICONS {
    const mapping = {
        'e-mail': 'file alternate outline',
        'document': 'file word outline',
        'table': 'file excel outline',
        'pdf': 'file pdf outline',
    }

    if (mapping[type]) {
        return mapping[type];
    }
    else {
        return 'question circle outline';
    }
}



//I WANT SOMETHING LIKE THIS.
export function myIconNameFromType(type) {
    const mapping = {
        'html': {html},
        'pdf': {pdf},
    }

    if (mapping[type]) {
        return mapping[type];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same thing but using css instead Icon component for some custom icon becouse with semantic if you want to edit icons/colors, you've to install everything locally, fight with theyr code and recompile it. if you just need some custom icons try with simple css to a div like i did:

```
.battery_custom_icom_sample:before {
    content: "\F240" !important;
    color: #c1bcbc2b;
    font-size: 130px;
    padding-top: 66px;
}
```

edit:

```
//you have to npm i lodash
import _ from 'lodash'

const mapping = [    
    {type:'e-mail', className:'custom1'},
    {type:'document', className: 'custom2'},
    {type:'table', className: 'custom3'},
    {type:'pdf', className: 'custom4'}
]


export function myIconNameFromType(type) {
   return  _.find(mapping, (i) => i.type === type).className
}
```

or without lodash:

```
export function myIconNameFromType(type) {
   return mapping.filter(function (el) {
         return el.type === type
   }).className
}
```

so:

```
<Icon className={this.myIconNameFromType(type)} />
```

Comment: Sadly I cant use this way. I have to use that function, my Icon component is in loop.

Comment: just pass the custom class to "className" instead the icon name to "name"

Comment: check your console log

Comment: TypeError: _lodash.default.find(...) is undefined

Comment: did you installed lodash? i'm using lodash library i nthe example to filter the object, you have to install it with "npm i lodash'

Comment: i installed it, restarted the server, still

Comment: "lodash": "^4.17.11",

Comment: devDependencie: "@types/lodash": "^4.14.123",

Comment: @Lovikuningas there was a missing "this" on the myIconNameFromType call, try to call it with <Icon className={this.myIconNameFromType(type)} />, is working on my machine

Comment: i dont have <Icon /> and func in same file. I import it: import { myIconNameFromType } from '~/src/components/file..';

Comment: Any ideas, how to do this without lodash?

Comment: @Lovikuningas edited with example without lodash, didn't tested but should work

Comment: i updated my upper code, maybe can give a advice now?